# how to Fit row height to content in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Any idea how to Fit row height to content in ng-grid? See that the text is wrapped but not shown as the row has a fix height.
I saw several posts claiming there is no support for that... thought maybe someone can enlighten me...

Thanks.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
this.gridOptions = { data: 'tenants.elements',      
        selectedItems: this.mySelections,       
        enableColumnResize: true,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        enableRowReordering: true,      
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
        showFooter: true,       
        //sortInfo: {fields: ['percent'], directions: ['desc']},
        columnDefs:
               [                    
                    {width: '7%', field:'apartment', displayName:'דירה'},
                    {width: '2%', field:'tenant_type', displayName:'-', cellTemplate: '<i ng-class="tenants.getTenantType(row.entity.tenant_type)" class="fa fa-child"></i>'},
                    {width: '2%', field:'defecto', displayName:'-', cellTemplate: '<i ng-show="row.entity.defecto" class="fa fa-child defecto"></i>'},                  
                    {width: '30%', field:'tenant_name', displayName:'שם דייר', cellTemplate: '<a href="#GetTenantsDebts/{{row.entity.building_id}}/{{row.entity.apartment}}">{{row.entity.tenant_name}}</a>'},
                    {width: '25%' ,field:'phones', displayName:'טלפונים'},
                    {width: '25%' ,field:'mails', displayName:'מיילים'}
                ],
        filterOptions: this.filterOptions,      
        plugins: [new ngGridAutoRowHeightPlugin()]
        //plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()]
        }
```

Comment: Check here for more info on variable row height in ng-grid. I think there's a plugin: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/21

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plugin, some code taken from the [ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-flexible-height.js)
Be warned, that height will be changed on all rows by maximum height

```
ngGridAutoRowHeightPlugin = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.grid = null;
    self.scope = null;

    self.init = function (scope, grid, services) {
        self.domUtilityService = services.DomUtilityService;
        self.grid = grid;
        self.scope = scope;


        var recalcHeightForData = function () { setTimeout(innerRecalcForData, 1); };
        var innerRecalcForData = function () {
            var gridId = self.grid.gridId,
                rowHeight = self.grid.config.rowHeight;

            $('.' + gridId + ' .ngRow [ng-cell-text]').each(function (index, cellText) {
                //+10 for default top and bottom padding of .ngCellText class
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, $(cellText).outerHeight() + 10); 
            });

            if (self.grid.config.rowHeight < rowHeight) {

                self.grid.config.rowHeight = rowHeight;

                //update grid's scope.rowHeight as vertical bars height depends on it
                if (scope.$$phase == '$apply' || scope.$$phase == '$digest') {
                    updateGridScopeHeight();
                } else {
                    scope.$apply(updateGridScopeHeight);
                }

                self.domUtilityService.RebuildGrid(self.scope, self.grid);

                function updateGridScopeHeight() {
                    self.grid.$root.scope().rowHeight = rowHeight;
                }
            }

        };

        self.scope.catHashKeys = function () {
            var hash = '',
                idx;
            for (idx in self.scope.renderedRows) {
                hash += self.scope.renderedRows[idx].$$hashKey;
            }
            return hash;
        };

        self.scope.$watch('catHashKeys()', innerRecalcForData);
        self.scope.$watch(self.grid.config.data, recalcHeightForData);
    };
};
```

And also, add this style rule to your css (after ng-grid css)

```
.ngCellText {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0J5XbE?p=preview)

Comment: Tried it in my code, didn't see any affect. also the plunker doesn't work. empty window

Comment: Did you attached this plugin to ngGrid instance? `$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', plugins: [new ngGridAutoRowHeightPlugin()] };`

Comment: Do you use custom row or columns templates?

Comment: yes. I'm using column templates. I've added the code to my question.

Comment: Code I posted expects default template. You need to fix this selector: `$('.' + gridId + ' .ngRow [ng-cell-text]')` (the `[ng-cell-text]` part) to fetch content height of cells and maybe add some class to allyour cell templates you want to take into account for calculating context height

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Is this the only copy of it? If so, you should consider submitting to the ng-grid people to make it an official plugin.